# The best way to setup port forwarding

Tags: linux, networking

I have a situation when I want to connect from Windows machine to a web server running in virtual machine in Linux host. For this I would like Linux host to listen on a certain port and redirect it to the guest OS.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

Give the web server VM direct access to the network card, that way you won't have to deal with the Linux host's firewall.

Otherwise, the port forwarding depends on what VM software you're using.